# Nginx : Cannot listen on port 80 ... only port 8080 works on OSX 10.11

Tags: macos, nginx

OSX 10.11
I installed the latest nginx 1.9.9 (from source and compiled )
the configuration file /usr/local/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok

when listening on port 8080 no problem I can request http://example.local:8080

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  example.local;
    root HTML;
```

And then run:

```
 sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "80"
 nginx     8254           root   10u  IPv4 0x643a3abbad7bf485      0t0     TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
 nginx     8392           yves   10u  IPv4 0x643a3abbad7bf485      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

BUT when I change the port to 80, I cannot reach http://example.local:80

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.local;
    root html;

sudo nginx -s reload
nginx     8254           root   10u  IPv4 0x643a3abbad7bf485      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx     8254           root   18u  IPv4 0x643a3abbadbb9485      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     8430           yves   10u  IPv4 0x643a3abbad7bf485      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx     8430           yves   18u  IPv4 0x643a3abbadbb9485      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Safari canot open the page
however I can still request http://example.local:8080

very weird .... Nginx IS LISTENING on 80 ...  what can I do ?

Comment: So what do the error logs say?

Comment: nothing   
/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log is empty
so is
/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log

when I look at the ps aux , the nginx: worker process is run by nobody...  is it right ?

Comment: And is the default (Apache) web server shutdown?

Comment: yes ...   I run 
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: How about `sudo apachectl stop`?

Comment: it is stopped 
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: FWIW I'm having exactly the same problem with v1.8.1 installed via homebrew.

Comment: seems to be teh rule on Mac OSX ... security first !  so I sticj with it and run all my tests on  ports > 1000

Comment: restart with launchctl

Answer (score 15):

You just can run services on ports below to 1024 as sudo.

Running on the go:

```
$ sudo brew services restart nginx
```

Starting with the system:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/local/opt/nginx/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Note that you must set up your server to listen to 80 inside your config file and make sure there's no other process running at port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Check firwall or iptables.

Port 80 might be blocked.  Try stopping firewall or iptables service.

If it is blocked, then add entry to allow port 80

Answer (score 0):

Run **top** in your the terminal and use F3 to search for the **NGINX** process.
Copy the **PID** number from the running **NGINX** process when you find in the **top** list running process.
Paste the PID number into `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`.
Just paste in the **PID** number on it's own on the first line of the `nginx.pid` file.
Even if already stopped it before STOP nginx `sudo nginx -s stop` and then start it again `sudo nginx`.

Nginx can't stop it's process because it doesn't know the **PID** number and the running instance is bound to the relative port blocking a second instances binding to the same port.

This was on MacOS Ventura, a fresh install. It happened because I changed the location of the **PID** file in the **NGINX** config file while it was running and therefore it couldn't stop itself.